# iPhone Blue Bar at top of screen

Tags: iphone, uiview

This is hands down the dumbest question I have ever had to ask but I have a blue bar appearing at the top of my view and I have no idea why or how to get rid of it.  The view is simply a UIView, not table or navigation its just a blank view but when I run the app in the simulator there is a blue bar across the top the size of a navigation or tool bar.  If you have any idea why this darn thing is there I would greatly appreciate it.
[image]

Comment: Is the view part of a navigation controller?

Comment: No its just a view.  Absolutely nothing else.  When i initially created the controlling class I had it setup as a UITableView object but I removed that and changed it to a UIViewController.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the silly sounding line of questions but have you done clean/build?  What about deleting the app entirely and reinstalling it?

Comment: I think this may be the problem.  I call this view from clicking on a table cell.  Under my didselectrowatindexpath I call this line: UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:relayView];
        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil]; Could that be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside the view will appear method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden  = YES;
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I did.  Thanks a lot.  I totally forgot I loaded the view using a Navigation Controller.  Don't I feel dumb.  Thanks again.